# How to get recent value in Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark data frame with following structure

```
id  flag price date
 a   0    100  2015
 a   0    50   2015
 a   1    200  2014
 a   1    300  2013
 a   0    400  2012
```

I need to create a data frame with recent value of flag 1 and updated in the flag 0 rows.

```
id  flag price date new_column
a   0    100  2015    200
a   0    50   2015    200
a   1    200  2014    null
a   1    300  2013    null
a   0    400  2012    null
```

We have 2 rows having flag=0. Consider the first row(flag=0),I will have 2 values(200 and 300) and I am taking the recent one 200(2014). And the last row I don't have any recent value for flag 1 so it is updated with null.

Looking for a solution using Scala. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use window functions.
Basically create a window where you partition by id and order by date. Then get the previous line for every line. Lastly, use when/otherwise to turn all cases with flag 1 to null.

Something like this:

```
val df = sc.parallelize(List(("a",0,100,2015),("a",1,200,2014),("a",1,300,2013),("a",0,400,2012))).toDF("id","flag","price","date")
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lag,when}
val wSpec1 = Window.partitionBy("id").orderBy("date")
val df2=df.withColumn("last1",when(df("flag")===0,lag('price, 1).over(wSpec1)).otherwise(null))
```

Comment: Thanks.Your solution work perfectly, While ordering there will be a chance to get multiple 0 flagged records sequentially .I updated my question with this use cases. Sorry again I missed this on the first time. @Assaf Mendelson